# Confusion on scikit-learn nested cross validation example

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

There are a ton of threads on nested cross-validation. ["An intuitive understanding of each fold of a nested cross validation for parameter/model tuning"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341229/an-intuitive-understanding-of-each-fold-of-a-nested-cross-validation-for-paramet?rq=1) gives a good explanation.
scikit-learn has [an example of what they refer to as nested cv](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html), but it seems wrong. Am I misunderstanding the example?

The inner cv step in the example makes sense. Use the inner cv step to get the best estimator.

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_
```

The outer cv step does not. It's using the same data as the inner cv step, which means that at least some of the data that has been used for training in the inner cv loop will be used for scoring in the outer cv loop. In other words, the outer cv loop is computing an average performance of the inner cv model, with no consideration as to what data has been already used for training.

```
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

I would expect the example to look like this:

```
# Loop for each trial
for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):
    outer_cv_scores = []
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    for train, test in outer_cv.split(X_iris, y_iris):
        # Non_nested parameter search and scoring. Do not use any of the test data.
        clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
        clf.fit(X_iris[train], y_iris[train])

        # Score the trained model from the inner cv step on the test data for this outer fold.
        outer_cv_scores.append(scorer(clf, X=X_iris[test], y=y_iris[test]))

    # For the final score for this trial, average the scores across all outer cv folds.
    score_for_trial = outer_cv_scores.mean()
```

Have I found a bug in this example or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: I think your understanding of nested CV is fine; good work and good question (+1). I believe you slightly misunderstood how `GridSearchCV()` will work within `cross_val_score()` and how this relates to a true nested CV procedure. Please see my answer below where I explain this in more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: The example is correct but not easy to follow. You understand things correctly around nested CV but you probably did not follow the example. I do not blame you; it took me a slow read to see it is right.

The example defines two K-Folds cross-validators. One called `inner_cv` and one called `outer_cv`. Notice that while both are simple 4-fold CV procedures they do *not* refer to the same data.

OK, let's go line by line now:

1. `clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)` says: Fit the estimator `svm` via a parameter search using `p_grid` using the cross_validation procedure is based on the `inner_cv` cross-validator.
2. Inner CV object is then used explicitly through the line `clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)`; we take the `X_iris` dataset, *all 150 instances of it*, break it into 4 pieces as dictated by `inner_cv` in `clf`, do CV using those 4 pieces (folds) and fit our object.
3. `clf.best_score_` then gives us the mean cross-validated score of the best estimator among the ones defined by hyperparameters `p_grid`.
4. `cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)` says: Give us the scores of the estimator `clf` for each run of the cross validation defined by `outer_cv`. To do that, `cross_val_score` will go ahead and do the following:

   1. Take the `X_iris` dataset, *all 150 instances of it*, break it into 4 pieces (this is our outer CV).
   2. In the three pieces that are defined by the the `outer_CV` (~113 instances) as our training *and* validation set, train the `clf` estimator (the `svm`) by taking a piece of ~85 instances and  validating the performance of that estimator using a piece of ~28 instances. After doing K (inner) repeats, return the best estimator among the ones defined by hyperparameters `p_grid`. (that is our inner CV)
   3. In the remaining one piece (~37 instances) that is our unseen test fold, it will go ahead and estimate the associated cost. To do that, it will take the best estimator as provided by the inner loop, use it to predict on the value on the test fold, compare their goodness of fit and finish up.
   4. This is repeated K (outer) times.

As you see the command `cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)` does exactly what you described in your code implementing nested CV. Just that function hides all the details; the primary detail being that `clf` is not really an previously optimised classifier object but rather a procedure where an inner procedure does a CV. To that extent, if `cross_val_score` was presented with an object that had the best parameters from `GridSearchCV` but did not do any internal CV itself, `cross_val_score` would effectively give us the same results as `GridSearchCV`.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. My confusion, like you mentioned, was due to thinking that `clf` was a previously optimised classifier object.

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help. Best of luck with the rest of your models!